# MDHA Project not loading

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I installed VS2013 Update2 and CTP1.1.
I'm trying to create a blank cordovaapp project. This error is appearing. How can I fix it?

> Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp.jsproj
>   : error  : The imported project "C:\Users\Vishal
>   Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk. 
>   Z:\VSProject\Projects\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp\SampleHybridApp.jsproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-Device Hybrid App projects do not work if there is a space in the project path (this is a Cordova related issue). In this case, your username has a space.

The only way to resolve this at present is create a different user without spaces in the name and create a new Hybrid app project.

Comment: I felt that if your project directory path has a space then it will not work . I repaired VS & CTP then created project without spaces in path and it worked while it's worth to note a space still exist in my source path [**Users\Vishal Dwivedi\AppData\Roaming\npm**]. 

By the way thanks to priyank.